# How to add a pair to a pandas cell value

Tags: python, pandas

So, I'm trying to add a pair to a specific value in python with pandas, and I'm lost.

I have two pandas data frames, one of them has 2 columns: the name of an image, and identity that belongs to the image.

> ```
>                img     id
> 17      000018.jpg   2464
> 27      000028.jpg   3670
> 46      000047.jpg   9177
> 55      000056.jpg    545
> ```

The other df contains iris_images.

> ```
>      iris_images
> 0          S1001
> 1          S1001
> 2          S1002
> 3          S1002
> 4          S1003
> ```

What I am trying to do is to add an iris_image to every identity. For example if the identity is 2464 then I want to add S1001 to it in a new column, if the identity is 3670, pair it with S1002, etc.
So the result would be:

> ```
>                img     id     iris_image
> 17      000018.jpg   2464          S1001  
> 27      000028.jpg   3670          S1002
> 46      000047.jpg   9177          S1003
> 55      000056.jpg    545          S1004
> ```

There are multiple images with the same id, and multiple iris_images with the same name. What I want to do is to every id assign the same iris name.

Like so:

> ```
>                img     id     iris_image
> 17      000018.jpg   2464          S1001  
> 27      000028.jpg   2464          S1001
> 46      000047.jpg   9177          S1003
> 55      000056.jpg    545          S1004
> ```

Unfortunately none of my ideas achieved the goal output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible duplicated values in `id` use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 = df_face.loc[df_face['id'].isin(identities)].copy()

s = df2['iris_images'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
df1['iris_image'] = df1.groupby('id', sort=False)['img'].ngroup().map(s)
print (df1)
           img    id iris_image
17  000018.jpg  2464      S1001
27  000028.jpg  2464      S1001
46  000047.jpg  9177      S1002
55  000056.jpg   545      S1003
```

---

If you modify values in `df1` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df_face`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I left out a rather important detail: There are multiple images with the same id, and multiple iris_images with the same name. What I want to do is to every id assign the same iris name. I added it to the original answer as well.

Comment: @rolez22 - Edited second solution.

Comment: I get the following erroe: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  newdf_face['iris_image'] = newdf_face.groupby('img', sort=False)['img'].ngroup().map(s)

Comment: @rolez22 - How is created `newdf_face` ?

Comment: It is created by getting the 249 most used identities, because there are 249 irises.

Comment: @rolez22 - there is no problem with your code for created it, I ask for possible add solution  for prevent warning